# Quotient Space of upper-semi circle

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

**Question:**

> Consider the unit circle $S^1 = \{(u,v)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid u^2 + v^2 = 1\}$ and subset $Z = \{(u,v)\in S^1\mid v\geq 0\} $. We glue $S^1$ along $\phi: Z\to S^1: (u,v)\mapsto(u,-v)$ to form the quotient space $X:= S^1/\phi$. What familiar topological space is $X$ homeomorphic to?

**My Progress so far:**

It seems to me that the upper half of the unit circle is being identified with the lower half, and we have to glue them together. My intuition tells me that the resulting space should just be the interval $[-1,1]$ since by the symmetry of the circle, identifying $v$ with $-v$ means that the only relevant information that survives is $u \in [-1,1]$.

Continuing with this idea, since $(0,1)\sim (0,-1)$ then the equivalence class here could be given by $[0]$. So, if I am correct in thinking that $X \cong [-1,1]$, would an explicit homeomorphism be given by $\psi: X\to [-1,1]$ such that $[x]\mapsto x$?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, you are identifying points with the same $x$ coordinate on the circle. So your interpretation should be correct. A priori the quotient is e.g. the upper half of the circle, which is homeomorphic to $[-1,1]$ via the map $(x,y) \in S^1/\varphi \to x$, as you are saying.

Comment: It is not clear what $X$  should be. Usually gluing  means to form $S^1 \cup_\phi S^1$.